# python socket programming with Tkinter GUI

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, tkinter

I am trying to make a game using server and client connection and so far I have just been playing around with the connection and sending lists and strings between the two. This haven't been too difficult to understand but now I want to use a Tkinter GUI for both server and client.

When I press a Button at, say the clients GUI, I want the same actions to appear in both windows. So if I press a Button and a text prints out on the GUI I want the same text to print out on the other GUI, how can I do this? I don't think it would be any problem to **send** the information inside the `mainloop()` but how can i receive information inside it?

It would be great if someone took the time to explain this for me, I have been searching on Google but I can't really find anything that I can understand. I am really new into programming so most codes that are on the web are too hard for me to understand if they aren't well commented.

Comment: probably you will need `threading` module to run blocking `recv` function.

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand.

Answer (score 0):

[Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is a high-level framework that makes creating networked applications relatively easy. A simple tcp echo server can be made in a few lines:

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor, endpoints

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

class EchoFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Echo()

endpoints.serverFromString(reactor, "tcp:1234").listen(EchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

It also integrates well with the tkinter event loop (see [this](https://github.com/racker/python-twisted-core/blob/master/doc/examples/tkinterdemo.py0) example). You should be able to merge these two examples to create the code that you want.